# How to Convert Binary file data to a physical type with a given MIME Type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, system.io.file, system.io.fileinfo

I have a database table (tbl_document) which contains details of files which were uploaded into it over time.

I want to write a console application to download these files to a given location.

The table has three pieces of information, which I should use:

The **FileContents** in `varbinary` format; 
The **MIME Type** (**contentType**) for each file, in nvarchar format for example something like this:

application/x-zip-compressed
application/msword
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
application/pdf
application/pdf

In MVC, I would have done something like this to perform this task:

```
public FileContentResult DownloadFile()
{
                FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(file.FileContents, file.ContentType);
                result.FileDownloadName = file.FileName;
                return result;
}
```

I have tried other ways to do this such as this one:

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
 FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(fileContents, contentType);
```

I couldn't really get to save the file using any of the above. Please could you help.

Many thanks.

Comment: If the table contains a 1:1 binary representation of the file, you should be able to just write the binary contents to a file with the appropriate file name and extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually solved it like this:

```
 // fileContents is the binary file being downloaded; I didn't need to use the MIME Types
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileContents);
        //write to file
        FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        ms.WriteTo(file);
        file.Close();
        ms.Close();
```